# How to give glass effect to the background in pyqt5 without background image

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have made an application using pyqt5 and I want to give a glass effect in it's background without background image. How to do this?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to see "through" the background of the window, showing a blurred effect of what is behind that window? If that's so, it cannot be directly done in Qt. Otherwise, can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to achieve a semi transparent background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want this ==> ***setWindowOpacity***

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowOpacity(0.5)

        self.resize(320,250)
        self.show()        


app = QApplication([])
window = main()
app.exec()
```